# adf selectOneChoice valueChangeListener not firing

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

My valueChangeListener for SelectOneChoice is not getting invoked when I am trying to select a value in the dropdown. It is invoked only when I click on the Blank Item in the dropdown (which we configure in ListOfValues). 
On some research I have learnt that in your valueChangeListener, we must add

> vce.getComponent().processUpdates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());

as our first line. But It is still not getting invoked on selection of any other value apart from null.

**Code for my SelectOneChoice**

```
<af:selectOneChoice value="#{bindings.Prefix.inputValue}"
                    label="#{bindings.Prefix.label}"
                    shortDesc="#{bindings.Prefix.hints.tooltip}"
                    id="soc3"
                    partialTriggers="formatIdId"
                    visible="#{bindings.Prefix.hints.visible}"
                    binding="#{backingBeanScope.CreateItemBackingBean.prefixField}"
                    required="#{bindings.ItemNumberType.attributeValue eq 'VPLU'}"
                    showRequired="#{bindings.Prefix.hints.mandatory}"
                      validator="#{backingBeanScope.CreateItemBackingBean.onValidatePrefix}"
                      autoSubmit="true"
                     valueChangeListener="#{backingBeanScope.CreateItemBackingBean.onChangePrefix}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.Prefix.items}" id="si3"/>
    <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false"
                        pattern="#{bindings.Prefix.format}"/>
</af:selectOneChoice>
```

**Code for my ValueChangeListener**

```
    public void onChangePrefix(ValueChangeEvent vce) {
         vce.getComponent().processUpdates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
         System.out.println("vce.getOldValue()"+vce.getOldValue());
        System.out.println("vce.getNewValue()"+vce.getNewValue());
        System.out.println("I am in changed prefix");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`valueChangeListener` will fire only when you submit form. You can use any submit action for it or just turn on `autosubmit` property on component.

If you need to catch selection event without actually submitting data, you should use `clientListener` and handle it with javascript functions.

Comment: I am using `autoSubmit=true` for my field.  I am making a selection in my SelectOneChoice and still I do not see my valueChangeListener being called.

Comment: @SoumyaR even if you click somewhere out of field?

Comment: found the issue, read above comments. Thanks for your help though

Comment: I had exactly the same problem  , and somehow setting  autoSubmit="true"   solved my issue . Very strange. May be it is related to other tags on my form ... and i just dont see the root cause of the issue .. anyway  .. thanks to everyone who answer and posted this post.

Answer (score 2):

It may be your required tag preventing the valueChangeListener from firing.

```
required="#{bindings.ItemNumberType.attributeValue eq 'VPLU'}"
```

If "required" returns true, valueChangeListener won't be executed.
Also, remove "showRequired" attribute completely. Is not only not necessary, but is confusing because it has a different condition than "required" attribute.

Try a bit of debugging and set required="false".You can also remove "validator", "visible", see if it works without them, then add them back one by one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, though the required tag was not the culprit, i tried removing each tags to find the issue. It was the Validator tag which was updating the model with setValueToEL and hence the valueChangeListener was not firing.

Comment: I had the same problem, although required="true" was necessary. The problem was solved by adding the tag autoSubmit="true".